# How to Add Separators after List items In CSS

Tags: html, css, separator

I am trying to create a List items and adding separators between them i tried everything but problems remains there. here is the image i want my list menu look like :-

[image]

the css and html code i am using is this :-

**HTML :-**

```
<p class="Categories">Categories</p>
<div class="Rectangle"></div>
<div class="Categories_Box box1 box2">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="">Today</a></li>
<div class="line1"></div>
<li><a href="#" class="yest">Yesterday</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="this_week">This Week</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="last_week">Last Week</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="last_month">Last Month</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS :-**

```
   .Categories {
  font-size: 29px;
  font-family: "Exo";
  color: rgb(237, 106, 61);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.869;
  position: absolute;
  left: 227.937px;
  top: 215px;
  z-index: 31;
}

.Rectangle {
  background-color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  position: absolute;
  left: 231px;
  top: 281px;
  width: 194px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: 29;
}


.Categories_Box ul{
 position:absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 1366px;
 height: 768px;
 z-index: 43;
 list-style:none;

}


.yest, .this_week, .last_week, .last_month {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Exo";
  text-decoration:none;
  color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.86;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  position:relative;
  left: -175px;
  top: -641.112px;
  z-index: 30;
}

.line1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 345.85px;
  top: 684.418px;
  z-index: 100;
}


.box2 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  position: absolute;
  left: 219px;
  top: 229px;
  width: 228px;
  height: 498px;
  z-index: 27;
}


.box1 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  left: 221px;
  top: 230px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 498px;
  z-index: 28;
}
```

after editing this code my top 20 list got vanish also i can't even see menu items. 
please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can create the look by giving your list items a dashed border-bottom. As a simple example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Title</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Element 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Element 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:140px;
    border:1px #eee solid;
    border-radius:10px;
}

li{
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc dashed;
}

a{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

li:first-child{
    border-bottom: solid grey;
}
li:first-child a{
    color: rgb(237, 106, 61);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/72vvksws/3/ for a working example.

Comment: Thats  a nice solution but i have more than just one lists items . here is my progress what i have done so far if i try to add dashed border it got messed up please help me : https://jsfiddle.net/deep90s/j5ptL32n/2/

Comment: @dssingh - this is the cleanest method to provide the look you want. To implement it in your example you would apply the CSS properties to a class [like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/0dq0ayt8/) so that only the sidebar gets those values.

Comment: With this the heading named "Title" also becomes a link i do need that what i should do for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying me after lot of trying i fixed my problem. It was the z-index property which was creating the problems. after setting the z-index property in right order i was able to add separators between the list items without using border property. Here is the code for that :-

HTML :-

```
<p class="t20_files">Top 20 Files</p>
<div class="Rectangle1"></div>
<div class="Outside_box1 Inside_Box1">
<div class="Categories_Box1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
<p class="line10">------------------------</p>
<li><a href="#">Yesterday</a></li>
<p class="line11">------------------------</p>
<li><a href="#">This Week</a></li>
<p class="line12">------------------------</p>
<li><a href="#">Last Week</a></li>
<p class="line13">------------------------</p>
<li><a href="#">This Month</a></li>
<p class="line14">------------------------</p>
<li><a href="#">Last Month</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
@import url(normalize.css);

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    background:url(../images/site_bg.png) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
/*------------------------------Background---------------------------*/



/*-----------------------------Horizontal Menu Starts----------------*/
.head-menu {
  background:url(img/menu_bg.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: 219px;
  top: 117px;
  width: 930px;
  height: 81px;


    }

.head-menu ul {
     list-style: none;
     position:relative;

}

.head-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 2.7;
    line-width: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1.96px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.39, 1.31);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.39, 1.31);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.39, 1.31);
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -53px;
    top: 2px;

    } 




    .home {
        margin-left:35px;
        }
    .allfiles {
        margin-left:70px;
        }

    .ulpd_by_usrs {
        margin-left:100px;
        }

    .upld_frm_mob {
        margin-left:130px;
        }
    .contact {
        margin-left:102px;
        }   
/*-----------------------------Horizontal Menu Ends----------------*/

/*--------------------------------------Top 20 Files Starts----------------------------*/

.Categories_Box1 ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style:none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1584px;
  z-index:96;

}

.Categories_Box1 li a {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Exo";
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 0.76907888849934,0,0,0.58955579248353,0,0);
  left: -34px;
  top: 38px;
  z-index:97;
}


.t20_files {
  font-size: 29px;
  font-family: "Exo";
  color: rgb(237, 106, 61);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.869;
  position: absolute;
  left: 227.937px;
  top: 734px;
  z-index:95;

}


  .Rectangle1 {
  background-color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  position: absolute;
  left: 231px;
  top: 799px;
  width:  218px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: 94;
}




.Outside_box1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  position: absolute;
  left: 219px;
  top: 748px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 326px;
  z-index: 92;
}

.Inside_Box1 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  left: 221px;
  top: 749px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 326px;
  z-index: 93;
}

.line10 {
  font-size: 28.12px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  left: 8.2px;
  top: -5.75px;
}
.line11 {
  font-size: 28.12px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  left: 8.2px;
  top: 35.75px;
}
.line12 {
  font-size: 28.12px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  left: 8.2px;
  top: 80.25px;
}
.line13 {
  font-size: 28.12px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  left: 8.2px;
  top: 123.75px;
}

.line14 {
  font-size: 28.12px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  line-height: 4.2;
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  left: 8.2px;
  top: 168.25px;
}


/*-----------------Top 20 Files Ends----------------------------*/
```

If You have any other ways to make use of just one line instead of using p class tag after every list item please post it so i can make my code short. Here is JS Fiddle link :- [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep90s/r8hczb69/)